# Hadoop cluster setup with cygwin

Tags: hadoop

I going to setup a hadoop cluster in my project(3nodes). My doubt is that we can continue using cygwin or should have linux os in my machine to setup the cluster?
In otherwords, setting up cluster using cygwin leads to pseduo distributed mode with single node or it is like a normal distributed cluster??

Please help me to understand

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to set up Hadoop cluster (CDH5.0.2 distribution) in pseduo mode with cygwin and it was hell. I had problems with classpaths, cygwin was unable to parse some paths from hadoop files so i had to rewrite some hadoop code. So I do not recommend using hadoop with cygwin.

Generaly if you just install hadoop with cygwin it is in pseudo distributed mode (see. [this](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows)) but of course you can install hadoop in distributed mode, but you need more nodes than 1. Think good about it is here [Running Hadoop on Windows](http://hayesdavis.net/2008/06/14/running-hadoop-on-windows/)